# Как склонять слово «результат»?

Tags: орфография, склонение

В лаборатории поступило для исследований 46 739 проб материала от свиней (получено 653 положительных результата).

Comment: как правильно результата или результатов

Answer (score 1):

У вас - правильно.  ***Получено 653 положительных результата.***

Форма падежа слова "результат" тут очевидна. Ей управляет последнее слово числительного, в данном случае **три.**  "Три результата" - значит и "563 результата".

> Числительные два, три, четыре (а также составные числительные,
> оканчивающиеся на два, три, четыре, например двадцать два) в
> именительном падеже сочетаются с существительным в форме родительного
> падежа и единственного числа, например: двадцать два стола, тридцать
> три несчастья, пятьдесят четыре человека. Числительные пять, шесть,
> семь, восемь, девять и т. д. и составные числительные, оканчивающиеся
> на пять, шесть, семь, восемь и т. д., согласуются с существительным,
> стоящим в форме родительного падежа множественного числа, например:
> сорок восемь преступников. Однако в косвенных падежах согласование
> выравнивается: р. п. – двух столов, пяти столов, д. п. – двум столам,
> пяти столам.

*http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/61-rubric-92*

При этом падеж определения ("положительный") выбирается по другим правилам. В мужском роде для всех числительных (кроме оканчивающихся на "один") он совпадает с родительным множественного.

Что касается классификации этого падежа и его истории, то это вопрос дискуссионный.  Падеж можно считать родительным, можно особым родительным или так называемой счетной формой. Точно так же в рамках исторической грамматики возможно соотнесение этой формы не только с двойственным числом, но и с обычным родительным, последнее объясняется историей самого имени числительного как части речи. При таком подходе на первый план выступает тот факт, что в относительно недавнем прошлом числительное в современном понимании как часть речи в русском языке отсутствовало, слова "два", "три" и "четыре" грамматически являлись существительными, а их управление было эквивалентно родительному падежу - "две сосны"  как "иголки сосны", "три стола" - как "ножка стола" и т. д.
*подробнее - по той же ссылке.*

Но это вопросы уже чисто академические, для практических нужд на уровне обычной грамотности вполне приемлемо считать этот падеж родительным - с небольшими отклонениями в формах типа "два час**а**, "шаг**а**" (при родительном "ч**а**са, ш**а**га").

(+)
Чтобы исключить недоразумение, добавлю, что некоторые авторы относят древнерусские слова "один", "два", "три" и "четыре" к категории счетных прилагательных, а не к особым существительным. Такое понимание базируется в основном на наличии родовых отличий у слов "один/одна/одно/одни" и "два/две". Вопрос для нас не принципиальный, грамматика этих категорийных классов в основном совпадает, но через прилагательное сложнее объяснить родительный падеж существительного.